# What is the "shell:" prefix in windows command line mean?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

I learned [here](http://lifehacker.com/5496548/how-to-launch-the-recycle-bin-from-the-start-menu-search-box) that I can type "shell:RecycleBinFolder" in the start menu and it will bring up the recyle bin -- and sure enough it does.

But what does "shell:" even mean? in what context does it have meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shell:` is a windows shortcut which permits access to a large number of windows attributes (commands, folders).

Here are some examples of the shortcuts to windows folders:

```
shell:System
shell:SystemCertificates
shell:SystemX86
shell:Templates
shell:TreePropertiesFolder
shell:UserProfiles
shell:UsersFilesFolder
shell:Windows
```

**Further Information**

[Reference to various shell: commands](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-shell-keyword.html)

and

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: They are all folders in the shell namespace, not commands